# Show/hide div on onMouseover and onMouseout.

Tags: javascript, html

Hey I have a very basic HTML code. There is some problem with the HTML event attributes. Check this code:

```
<td ><div id="id" onMouseover="show()" onMouseout="hide()">
       <table width=100%>
        <tr><td>hiiii</td></tr>
                     </table>
                     </div></td>
```

here's the script :

```
<script>
         function show() {  document.getElementById('id').style.visibility="visible";  }
         function hide() {    document.getElementById('id').style.visibility="hidden";  }
</script>
```

The output displays **hiiii** no matter what.

Comment: Please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` should be in all lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with the scope of the html event handler attributes. There's two easy solutions:

Make the `show` and `hide` functions [available in the global scope](http://jsfiddle.net/obnzbpmd/):

```
window.show = function () { document.getElementById('id').style.visibility="visible"; }
window.hide = function () { document.getElementById('id').style.visibility="hidden"; }
```

Or put the [event handlers in your JavaScript code](http://jsfiddle.net/obnzbpmd/1/), instead of HTML attributes:

```
var div = document.getElementById('id');
div.onmouseover = show;
div.onmouseout = hide;
function show() { document.getElementById('id').style.visibility="visible"; }
function hide() { document.getElementById('id').style.visibility="hidden"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` attributes should be in lower case.

So:

```
<div id="id" onmouseover="show()" onmouseout="hide()">
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/jsbrown/pen/c99cf25c75477c873553574f111935b7)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <td>
     <div id="id" onmouseover="show()" onmouseout="hide()">
       <table width="100%">
          <tr><td id="test">
                            hiiii
               </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
   </td>

 function show() {
     document.getElementById('test').style.visibility = "visible";
    }
 function hide() {
        document.getElementById('test').style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
```

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/obnzbpmd/8/

When Div is hidden it doesn't call the JS hide() function. you need to set ID on the control ifself which you want to show/hide based on condition and assign event handlers on the Main Div element.

Hope this helps and hope this is what you are looking for!